# I want to destroy particles by another particles in unity

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am making a game like fire fighter and I had made a fire by particles system , and using fire extinguisher just a prefab, which emitting another particles and iI want when 2nd particles collides with first particles (fire) then first particles (fire) will destroy?
Any Suggestions? Thanks in Advance.. :-) 
I had already tried about particle colliding and some others
like

```
  collision col;
  if(gameObject.name=="Particle")
  Destroy(col.gameObject);
```

Comment: If you attach this script to `Water` particle, and you have a `Fire` particle, then just `if (other.gameObject.name=="Fire") Destroy(other.gameObject);`

Comment: You'd probably want to fake the interaction so you have more control over the gameplay elements. By all means detect where the water intersects your fire (could be a simple collider at the base of the flame) but consider controlling the 'health' of the fire particles (eg: constrict the emission rate, size) based on your logic - and save yourself a great deal of tinkering with both particlesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach this script to `Water` particle, and you have a `Fire` particle, then in your water collision script

```
if (other.gameObject.name=="Fire")
{
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    // bonus effect for smoke particles
    // Instantiate(smokeObject, other.gameObject.transform.position, other.gameObject.transform.rotation);
}
```